# creating a deployment.yaml for kubevirt for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, istio, blue-green-deployment

My end goal is to create a blue green deployment however I cannot find an example how I can implement a deployment file using this kind of template https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/ as when configuring istio for blue green deployment this is required. I have worked through lab1 and lab2 I have 2 vms(vm1, vm2) https://kubevirt.io/labs/kubernetes/lab1 after all the prerequisites/installtion/setup for kubeVirt

```
$ cat pvc_fedora.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: "fedora"
  labels:
    app: containerized-data-importer
  annotations:
    cdi.kubevirt.io/storage.import.endpoint: "https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/33/Cloud/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-33-1.2.x86_64.raw.xz"
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

I have the 2 VM's running. I can ssh into then and run webservice and access externally.

When I try to implement blue green deployment the same method that works for application in docker does not work for this. I have 5 manifests files `deployment.yml  gateway.yml  route-test.yml  route.yml  service.yml`

`deployment.yaml` is taken from how to implement using an application https://semaphoreci.com/blog/continuous-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes . how can I change this to implement and deploy VM's

This is my basic file on how I deploy a VM

```
$ cat vm1_pvc.yml 
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-07-04T15:03:08Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    kubevirt.io/os: linux
    app: myapp
  name: vm1
spec:
  running: true
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/domain: vm1
        app: myapp
    spec:
      domain:
        cpu:
          cores: 2
        devices:
          disks:
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: disk0
          - cdrom:
              bus: sata
              readonly: true
            name: cloudinitdisk
        machine:
          type: q35
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 1024M
      volumes:
      - name: disk0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fedora
      - cloudInitNoCloud:
          userData: |
            #cloud-config
            hostname: vm1
            ssh_pwauth: True
            disable_root: false
            ssh_authorized_keys:
            - ssh-rsa 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 sytel@openstack
        name: cloudinitdisk
```

The VM part is all working, active and running, but I want implement blue/green deployment for VM's

I have tried this file but it fails

**# manifests/deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-$COLOR_TEST
  labels:
    app: myapp
    color: $COLOR_TEST
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
      color: $COLOR_TEST
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-07-04T15:03:08Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    kubevirt.io/os: linux
    app: myapp
  name: vm1
spec:
  running: true
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/domain: vm1
        app: myapp
    spec:
      domain:
        cpu:
          cores: 2
        devices:
          disks:
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: disk0
          - cdrom:
              bus: sata
              readonly: true
            name: cloudinitdisk
        machine:
          type: q35
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 1024M
      volumes:
      - name: disk0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fedora
      - cloudInitNoCloud:
          userData: |
            #cloud-config
            hostname: vm1
            ssh_pwauth: True
            disable_root: false
            ssh_authorized_keys:
            - ssh-rsa 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 sytel@openstack
        name: cloudinitdisk
```

Fails with

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yml 
error: error validating "deployment.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "running" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "domain" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[1]): unknown field "cloudInitNoCloud" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Volume, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): missing required field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I have come across this page but what I want to deploy is a disk image https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/virtual-machines/ in this example it would be a fedora disk or replacing it with an ubuntu disk etc

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and reduce it to a [mcve]?  There is a lot of detail around, for example, Istio ingress that seems secondary to the question you're actually asking.  The final YAML file does not look like a normal Deployment (compare to the second one in the question) and possibly you have a more specific question about the `VirtualMachine` resource?

Comment: I have updated it